# passing arguments to a function using kwargs - Python

Tags: python

I have the following code snippet:

```
kwargs = {'inventory_file' : self.inventory_file}
for ts in self.test_sets_list:
   current_ts = TestSet(name=ts,
                        test_cases=self.test_sets_list[ts],
                        om_ip_address=self.om_ip_address,
                        **kwargs)


class TestSet(object):
   def __init__(self, name, test_cases, om_ip_address, **kwargs):


class TestCase(object):
        def __init__(self, parameters, config_file, test_failure,
                 om_ip_address, **kwargs):
```

I know I'm probably doing wrong, because in `**kwargs` I'm unpacking the values in `kwargs`. What I want is to pass the arguments of `kwargs` all the way to `TestCase`. Inside `TestSet` I'm trying to pass the `kwargs` argument:

```
instance = TestCase(parameters=params, 
                    config_file=cnf,
                    om_ip_address=om_ip_address,
                    **kwargs)
```

However I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 258, in <module>
    main(args)
  File "main.py", line 217, in main
    operation.collect_tests()
  File "main.py", line 157, in collect_tests
    **kwargs)
  File "test_set.py", line 47, in __init__
    self.__instantiate_module(tc, om_ip_address)
  File "test_set.py", line 78, in __instantiate_module
    **self.kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'inventory_file
```

The class is instantiated via:

```
    my_class = getattr(module, test_cases['name'])
    instance = my_class(parameters=params, 
                        config_file=cnf,
                        om_ip_address=om_ip_address)
```

How can I be able to pass `kwargs` all the way to `TestCase`?

Comment: I don't think the TypeError is actually occurring on any of the lines of code you posted. Please post the full Traceback error message.

Comment: @unutbu that's all ...

Comment: Please post the code defining `__instantiate_module`.

Comment: @unutbu added... please take a look

Comment: What you posted does not define `__instantiate_module`, and it doesn't contain the line with `**self.kwargs`. What is the function that ends with `**self.kwargs)`? That's what we really need to see. The error is generated on line 78 of `test_set.py`. At the minimum we need to see that line. Additional lines preceding line 78 may be helpful for context too.

Answer (score 1):

Calling a function with `**kwargs`, where `kwargs = {'inventory_file' : self.inventory_file}` is the same as calling

```
function(inventory_file=self.inventory_file)
```

and if the definition of `function` doesn't have inventory_file in the accepted params list, it will throw the error you got there.
Two ways to solve this:

```
class TestCase(object):
    # add inventory_file to the params list with a default value
    def __init__(self, parameters, config_file, test_failure,
             om_ip_address, inventory_file=None, **kwargs):
        self.inventory_file = inventory_file
```

or:

```
class TestCase(object):
    # check for the inventory file in the kwargs dict
    def __init__(self, parameters, config_file, test_failure,
             om_ip_address, **kwargs):
        if 'inventory_file' in kwargs:
             self.inventory_file = kwargs['inventory_file']
```

and in both cases:

```
>>> t = TestCase('param1','param2','param3','param4', **{'inventory_file':'file'})
>>> t.inventory_file
'file'
```